# Windows 10 Ошибка 0xc000021a и ошибка 0хс000001

Tags: windows-10, bios

Всем привет, у меня такая проблема:
Вылетела вот такая ошибка (Ошибка 0xc000021a и ошибка 0хс000001), я сделал в строке команду sfc scannow, но она не помогла, а только указала, какой файл поврежден. Могу ли я с флешки просто восстановить винду? Без не сноса и форматирования диска, у меня там очень важные данные.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ставлю загрузочную флешку с 10 виндой, но почему то она не грузится и просто остаётся на этом этапе. (Все приоритеты а биосе поставил, и защиту загрузки с флешки отключил), купил другую флешку и записал на неё установочник 10 винды, а биос ее вообще не видит, подскажите в чем проблема? [введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6t8d.jpg)

Comment: Попробуйте через Boot menu загрузиться с флешки.

Comment: Я пробовал, 1 флешку он просто не грузит, а 2 флешку не видит даже

Comment: а вы точно сделали загрузочную флешку?

Comment: Да, с помощью 1 флешки знакомый сам ставил 2 недели назад винду, а свою 2 флешку через официальное приложение сделал, возможно ли то, что мой биос не видит флешку 2.0? Так как он старый у меня